# AsyncTask com um ou vários métodos

Tags: android, asynctask

Gostaria de saber quais seriam as vantagem e desvantagens de utilizar uma classe estendida da `AsyncTask`, que contenha somente um ou diversos métodos.

**Exemplo:**

- Crio uma `AsyncTask` **para cada** processamento em background que irei
  utilizar.

**ou**

- Crio uma `AsyncTask` **para todos** processamentos, e dentro dela crio
  diversos métodos, e os chamo com um parâmetro ao instanciar a classe
  ?

**É algo a ser considerado, ou somente em questão de organização, necessidade, preferência, ou até boas práticas ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não só neste caso mas qualquer que seja a situação pode/deve considerar outras abordagens.

No entanto deve ter em consideração não a organização, necessidade, preferência, ou até boas práticas mas sim o que é mais adequado para a situação em causa.

Deverá começar por considerar usar uma AsyncTask para cada processamento.
Se, durante o desenvolvimento, verificar que existem processamentos com características semelhantes pode considerar escrever uma classe única para os processar.

Não da forma como descreve o seu segundo exemplo que, se eu entendi bem, necessitará da implementação de alguma lógica para poder tratar os diferentes processamentos. Isso não só complicará a classe como complicará a sua utilização.

Por isso falei em "processamentos com características semelhantes".
Por exemplo, se tem um conjunto de processamentos que não retornam nada e requerem que um ProgressBar seja apresentado, pode escrever uma classe estendida de AsyncTask onde implementa todos os métodos excepto o `doInBackground()`.

Quando tiver um processamento desse tipo bastará implementar esse método:

```
new GenericAsyncTask() {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        //inserir aqui o processamento a executar
        return null;
    }
}.execute();
```

Este é apenas um exemplo, outros dependerão do tipo de processamentos a processar.

Comment: Exatamente nesse contexto em ter várias necessidades "iguais", e assim criar uma AsyncTask com vários métodos, e por parâmetro, você passar qual deve ser chamado, e no doInBackground faz o `if` para chamar o método relativo. Por exemplo uma calculadora com cálculos demorados, que pode calcular de várias formas mas sempre só terá 1 número como entrada e 1 resultado de saída. Sobre a  GenericTask, seria instanciado dentro de uma classe qualquer ?

Comment: Não "gosto" da solução de ter vários `if` no entanto, como digo na resposta, se acha que é adequado ao seu caso use. Sim pode ser instanciada em qualquer classe, desde que a instância seja criada na *UI thread*.